# Symfony 2 setAttributes() instead of setEmail(), setPassword(), etc

Tags: symfony

I love Symfony 2 very much. I am really grateful to you (Symfony team) for such an awesome framework.  But, recently I came across a problem. Actually, I moved from Yii to Symfony 2. In Yii, there is an attribute namely "attributes" which is very helpful. Because I don't have to set all the attributes for my model like below:

I just do:

```
$account = new Account();
$account->attributes = $_POST['Account'];
```

instead of

```
$account = new Account();
$account->email = 'example@gmail.com';
$account->password = '1111111111';
```

This is very helpful because if I want to add some attributes to my model (Account) in the future, I don't have to hunt for the places where I have to add these new attributes.

But in Symfony 2, I have to do like this:

```
$account = new Account();
$account->setEmail('example@gmail.com');
$account->setPassword('1111111111');
```

So my question is that "Is there a function in Symfony 2 that does the job of '**attributes**' in Yii?".

Comment: In your specific example, the S2 form processor will take care of binding $_POST to your entities.  You could add setAttributes() to your entities but I think after you use the framework for a bit you will find that it's not really all the useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to mimic that behavior, you could always do something like this:

```
class Account
{
    // ... snip ...

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return Account
     */
    public function fromArray(array $data = array())
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $method = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
            if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
                $this->{$method}($value);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: N.B! This is not safe. Some methods (like password hash or user group id, is_admin) can be setted by user but you doesn't want it. https://github.com/blog/1068-public-key-security-vulnerability-and-mitigation

Answer (score 1):

Create custom repository class for the entity something like this:

```
// src/Acme/YourBundle/Repository/AccountRepository.php
namespace Acme\YourBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class AccountRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function SetAttributes($data)
    {
    //
    $account = new \YourBundle\Entity\Account();
    // your setters
    }
}
```

More info: [custom repository classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)